# Django API error "not field.remote_field.through._meta.auto_created"

Tags: django-rest-framework

My Django rest framework throws an error whenever I try to get the list of users from the endpoint.
The error is:

```
...
...
not field.remote_field.through._meta.auto_created
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Below is the user models

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="profile_images", null=True, blank=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
```

Below is my views

```
class UserListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
```

Below is my serializers

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    wallet_balance = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_wallet_balance(self, obj):
        user_wallet = UserWallet.objects.filter(user=obj)
        if not user_wallet.exists():
            return 0.00
        return user_wallet.get().get_balance()["amount__sum"]

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "email", "phone_number", 'wallet_balance')
```

Below is the wallet models. I have a method called get_balance which isn't included here

```
class UserWallet(models.Model):
    wallet_id = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    user = models.OneToOneField("accounts.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="wallet")
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="NGN")

    def get_balance(self):
        query = (Q(status="success") | Q(status="processing")) & Q(wallet=self)
        balance = WalletTransaction.objects.filter(query).aggregate(Sum("amount"))
        return balance
```

What can do I do solve this problem

Comment: Could you please show the content of the `User` model and all of the above three get_... functions in the `UserProfileSerializer`?

Comment: I've edited the question to include more details

Comment: What is the `get_balance()` function in the line `return user_wallet.get().get_balance()["amount__sum"]`?

Comment: Its just a function to that returns a number (balance).

Comment: Please upload all codes that are related. So that I could find the errors.

Comment: I've added the `get_balance()` method to the question

Comment: Did you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in settings.py file?

Comment: Can you show the all the code of the `User` class?